# is there anyway to use appendchild for once?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a button on my Login page, when you click, it became invisible and instead of that button You ll see a span. the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enterSystem() {
        document.getElementById("btnLogin").style.display = "none";
        var newtext = document.createTextNode("Wait...");
        document.getElementById("brain13").appendChild(newtext);
    }
</script>
```

ASP side:

```
<span class="lblMessageLoading" id="brain13" onclick="enterSystem();">
<asp:button class="LoginButton" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" runat="server" onclick="btnLogin-Click" /> </span>
```

so...the problem is that every time i click on "wait..." it keep writing the newtext which is the same text.
I want to know if there is a way to stop this problem.
thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example code, it would be easiest to just add a check to see if the "btnLogin" button already is invisible, like so:

```js
function enterSystem() {
    var loginButton = document.getElementById("btnLogin");
    if (loginButton.style.display !== "none"){
        loginButton.style.display = "none";
        var newtext = document.createTextNode("Wait...");
        document.getElementById("brain13").appendChild(newtext);
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer to work with css classes indicating document state, as this allows for easy testing, debugging and it'll keep the styling in the stylesheet (and it can affect several elements at once using a single state).

I'd add this to the page stylesheet:

```css
body.loginActive #btnLogin
{
    display: none;
}
```

And then rewrite the enterSystem function:

```js
function enterSystem()
{
    //  this uses classList which is rather new (http://caniuse.com/classlist)
    //  you may want to rewrite this into a test using a regular expression
    //  e.g. if (/\bloginActive\b/.test(document.body.className))
    if (!document.body.classList.contains('loginActive'))
    {
        //  the classList again, you may want to write this as:
        //  document.body.className += ' loginActive';
        document.body.classList.add('loginActive');
        var newtext = document.createTextNode("Wait...");
        document.getElementById("brain13").appendChild(newtext);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have any problem with my button, the only problem here is that by clicking on the <span> it keep writing the same text which is "wait..".